# Inertia.js - "usePage must be used within the Inertia component" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I'm encountering an issue with Inertia.js where I'm getting the error "usePage must be used within the Inertia component." I'm using `usePage` in my translations file (`translations.jsx`), and it seems to be causing a problem. The error is pointing to line 9 in `usePage.ts`.

Here's the simplified snippet of my code:

```
// app.jsx
import React from "react";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";
import { __ } from "./Shared/translations";

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

InertiaProgress.init({
    color: "#5e20d5",
    height: "10px",
    showSpinner: true,
});

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        const root = createRoot(el);

        root.render(<App {...props} />);

        window.__ = __;
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

```
// translations.jsx
import { usePage } from "@inertiajs/react";

export function __(key, replace = {}) {
    const { language } = usePage().props;
    if (language && language[key]) {
        let translation = language[key];
        
        Object.keys(replace).forEach(function (key) {
            translation = translation.replace(':' + key, replace[key]);
        });

        return translation;
    } else {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Can someone please suggest an alternative approach or identify what might be causing this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following approach:

In your translations.jsx file, instead of directly accessing the page props (which won't work), declare a variable to hold the language state:

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useState('');
```

Then, set the state when the app renders for the first time in app.jsx:

```
setup({ el, App, props }) {
    const language = props.initialPage.props.language
    const root = createRoot(el);

    // here set the language state

    ...
},
```

Then whenever the langauge changes (not on a full page relaod), just update the state directly.